# Copy zip file and unzip using puppet in windows 10

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to copy one file using puppet in windows.

Code is as below :-

```
file { 'D:\mycopy\folder\filename':
          ensure => present,
          mode => '0660',
          source => "d:\temp\test.zip",
}
```

---

It is giving me below error

Cannot use opaque urls' file:\d:   est\test.zip

I want to unzip also after copy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puppet recognizes both backslashes (\) and forward slashes (/) as path separators in Windows file names.  Although Windows shells want the former, the latter is a lot safer to use in Puppet manifests.

In this case, the two appearances of `\t` in your double-quoted path string will be interpreted as [escape sequences](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.3/lang_data_string.html#escape-sequences) representing the tab character.  You could solve that issue in this case by doubling the backslashes, by switching to a single-quoted string, or by switching to forward slashes.  As a matter of style, I would *both* switch to single quotes (because there are no variable interpolations or single quotes in the string content) and switch to forward slashes:

However, the actual diagnostic about opaque URLs is a clue to another issue: Puppet accepts URLs as values of `File`'s `source` parameter, and it is interpreting your absolute filename as a URL with scheme 'd'.  To work around this, you should express the source via a `file:` URL:

```
  source => 'file://d:/temp/test.zip'
```